# Python BeautifulSoup, Получить значение атрибута элемента

Tags: python, beautiful-soup

Есть html, например:

```
<div class="foo">
<a class="link" href="https://google.com">Неважно что тут</a>
</div>
```

Мне нужно получить только значение атрибута элемента, то есть: https://google.com
Или полностью весь html внутри элемента с классом foo (`<a class="link" href="https://google.com">Неважно что тут</a>`)

Есть код, который получает текстовое содержимое элемента.
Как мне его подправить для этой задачи?

```
def get_html (request):
    return BeautifulSoup(request, 'lxml')

def save_file(text):
    with open(output_filename, "a", encoding='utf8') as hello_file:
        print(text, file=hello_file)


def parse(url):
     r = request(url)
     html = get_html(r)

     items = html.select('div[class=foo]')
     for item in items:
         text = item.text
         save_file(text)
```

Банальная замена text = item.text на text = item.html не работает.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def save_file(text):
    with open('url.txt', "a", encoding='utf8') as f:
        f.write(text + '\n')

html = '<div class="foo">' \
       '<a class="link" href="https://google.com">Неважно что тут</a>' \
       '<a class="link" href="https://google2.com">Неважно что тут</a>' \
       '<a class="link" href="https://google3.com">Неважно что тут</a>' \
       '<a class="link" href="https://google4.com">Неважно что тут</a>' \
       '</div>'\
       '<div class="foo">' \
       '<a class="link" href="https://google5.com">Неважно что тут</a>' \
       '<a class="link" href="https://google6.com">Неважно что тут</a>' \
       '<a class="link" href="https://google7.com">Неважно что тут</a>' \
       '<a class="link" href="https://google8.com">Неважно что тут</a>' \
       '</div>'

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
links = [item['href'] for item in soup.select('div.foo a')]

for i in links:
    save_file(i)
```

Comment: Спасибо. Но дело в том, что я хочу весь результат сохранить в файл, поэтому в изначальном примере используется цикл.
Ваш вариант работает, но когда я пытаюсь впихнуть это в цикл, то мне ругается на самые разные синтаксические ошибки.

for item in items:
links = [item['href']
save_file(text)

Т.е элементов с нужным классом может быть несколько и все их атрибуты нужно сохранить в файл.

Comment: тогда вот так. исправил

Answer (score 2):

Используя `.select('div.foo a')`, вы сможете получить все `<a>`, находящиеся внутри `<div class="foo">`. Потом обойти список и извлечь значение атрибута `href`.

```
In [21]: html
Out[21]: '<div class="foo"><a class="link" href="https://google.com">Неважно что тут</a></div>'

In [22]: soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')

In [23]: items = soup.select('div.foo a')

In [24]: items
Out[24]: [<a class="link" href="https://google.com">Неважно что тут</a>]

In [25]: links = [item['href'] for item in items]

In [26]: links
Out[26]: ['https://google.com']
```

Comment: На такую конструкцию питон ругается.
inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation

Comment: @Amigo9876 похоже, в вашем коде для отступов используются и табы, и пробелы. В питоне принято использовать 4 пробела для отступов. Попробуйте все табы заменить на пробелы.